# how to include a dark border to bright segmented image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation, threshold

I have an image like this.note that the regions are not perfectly shaped.it is rectangular like region and ellipse like region. I have segmented the ellipse like region using some algorithm.segmented region is bright one.the border (red rectangle) is dark one
finally i must get red rectangular like region
can you suggest any algorithm to perform this

Comment: I struggle to understand a bit, so you've managed to segment the ellipse region (labelled as red ellipse), but you want to add a rectangular border to it? Also, can you tell us what form is your ellipse region? Is it a matrix of your image size with 0 else where and color red where the ellipse is?

Comment: I understand that English may not be your first language (neither is mine), and often is quite hard to explain the problems properly in a language that you dont really master, but you need to sit down and make a bit extra effort in this case. Unfortunately ti is very understand what you have and what you want with the given text

Comment: Can you maybe upload the image you're actually processing and say "this region I want", "this region I don't want", "this is the border of the region I want", etc. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you have done some real progress on your segmentation. Because you already have an idea of the location of elements you want to segment, you should use a watershed with constraints/markers:

1. Your actual segmentation represents the inner markers.
2. You dilate it with a big structuring element (bugger than the inter disk space).
3. You take the contour of the dilation, and that's your outer markers.
4. You compute the gradient of the original image.
5. You apply the watershed on the gradient image, using the markers you have just computed.

[EDIT] As the segmentation you provided does not match with the original image (different dimensions), I had to simulate roughly a simple segmentation, using [this image](http://www.thibault.biz/StackOverflow/Result_Markers2.png) (the red lines being the the segmentation you already have). And I got [this result](http://www.thibault.biz/StackOverflow/Result_Vertebras2.png).